# How to append object to DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, dom

I like to create an object myself like so:

```
function Table()
{

};
Table.prototype.toString = function ( ) 
{
    return '<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>';
};
var table = new Table();

$('body').append(table);
```

However did failed. So what is the trick to pull this off for your own objects? Something similiar can be seen with image.

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = '//some_image.jpg';
$('body').append(image);
```

Now I am not interested in the equilevant of table. Table is just an example of my own object.

Comment: You'd have to call `toString()` explicitly or make the constructor return a DOM node. `Image` inherits from a DOM node somehow, but you cannot create custom objects which inherit from `Node`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function Table()
{
    return document.createTextNode("That´s a table");
};
```

Something that definetly works:

```
Table.prototyp.toDOM = function()
{
    return document.createTextNode("That´s a table");
};

$("body").append(table.toDOM());
```

Comment: I read (http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/) that, your method is indeed the best way to go.

Comment: Why don't you return an actual `document.createElement("table")`? And your prototyp is missing an "e"

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  var htmlCon = "<div id='iconDiv'><table style='align:center;color:#fff;'></table></div>";
  $('body').append(htmlCon);
  $('#iconDiv').addClass("iconDiv").css({"left":xPos+20, "top":yPos-80});
  $('#iconDiv table').append('<tr><td colspan="4" style="color:#000"><b>Event</b></td><td align="right" valign=""><ahref="javascript:close()">X</a></td></tr>');
  $('#iconDiv table').append('<tr><td>When</td><td>:</td><td>'+""+day+""+'-'+""+monthName+""+' - '+""+year+""+'</td></tr>');
  $('#iconDiv table').append('<tr><td>What</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" name="wht" id="wht"><input type="hidden" name="start" id="start" value='+"'"+year+""+'-'+""+month+""+'-'+""+day+"'"+'><input type="hidden" name="end" id="end" value='+"'"+year+""+'-'+""+month+""+'-'+""+day+"'"+'></td></tr>');
  $('#iconDiv table').append('<tr><td colspan="5">e.g. Tea at the Ritz</td></tr>');
  $('#iconDiv table').append('<tr><td colspan="5"><input type="button" value="createEvent" class="button" onclick="CreateEvent()">&nbsp;<input class="button" type="button" value="editEvent" onclick="editEvent('+"'"+year+"'"+','+"'"+month+"'"+','+"'"+day+"'"+')"></td></tr>');</script>
```